# Reformatting Python datetime variables to match existing database (in Stata)

Tags: python, datetime, stata, datetime-format

This is a little niche, but I'm working as a data analyst for a nonprofit who is currently transitioning from using Stata to using Python. The database they keep is stored as an Excel file, but they mainly interact with it via Stata do files. As I'm 'translating' these do files over to Python, I'm struggling to work with the datetime variables. Cleaning is easy enough & it's no problem to convert the variable into a datetime object. But I can't figure out how to get the correct format of the datetime variable within Python. The database has all dates stored using the Stata default file format, which is %tcDDmonCCYY_HH:MM:SS. The challenge here is the "mon" part, the three-letter abbreviation of the month, lowercase, in between days & year. Python doesn't seem to have an easy character code for this three-letter month syntax... and I could do it manually but then the variable will be a string, not a datetime object.

So, tl;dr - the question at hand: how can I reformat the Python datetime object to be of the format DDmonYYYY HH:MM:SS, while remaining a datetime object? How to get the three-letter, uncapitalized month in the middle there?

Comment: Is changing the Stata do-files that generate this data an option? You can export in a different format. Also data does not store the dates in that format. They store it as a number. When the data was exported to Excel the Stata code was set to export the string representation of the date and not the underlying data.

Comment: Another idea, import that date string as a string to Python, then use `.replace()` to convert the `mon` to a format of your preference. There are only 12 months so it should not be too hard.

Comment: @TheIceBear I hear you, these are good ideas. Just talked with my supervisors, it might be possible to change the master dataset's datetime format. Issue is that dataset has over a million entries, so it may get hairy. I don't quite understand your second idea; do you mean import the datetime variables from the already existing master dataset? I'm worried I'll end up with variables that aren't datetime objects, but I can give it a go! Thank you very much for these ideas.